# Sortable table - error on first column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table that must be sortable alphabetically. All the columns are working fine, except the first one. For example, when the first column's header is clicked, it sorts a book's title that starts with "D" being the last one, instead of another title which starts with "Z". How can I fix it?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wy7zojza/

```js
$(function() {

  // these default equivalents were obtained from a table of equivalents
  // provided by sugar.js sorting alogrithms: http://sugarjs.com/sorting
  /*
  $.tablesorter.characterEquivalents = {
    'a' : '\u00e1\u00e0\u00e2\u00e3\u00e4\u0105\u00e5', // áàâãäąå
    'A' : '\u00c1\u00c0\u00c2\u00c3\u00c4\u0104\u00c5', // ÁÀÂÃÄĄÅ
    'c' : '\u00e7\u0107\u010d', // çćč
    'C' : '\u00c7\u0106\u010c', // ÇĆČ
    'e' : '\u00e9\u00e8\u00ea\u00eb\u011b\u0119', // éèêëěę
    'E' : '\u00c9\u00c8\u00ca\u00cb\u011a\u0118', // ÉÈÊËĚĘ
    'i' : '\u00ed\u00ec\u0130\u00ee\u00ef\u0131', // íìİîïı
    'I' : '\u00cd\u00cc\u0130\u00ce\u00cf', // ÍÌİÎÏ
    'o' : '\u00f3\u00f2\u00f4\u00f5\u00f6\u014d', // óòôõöō
    'O' : '\u00d3\u00d2\u00d4\u00d5\u00d6\u014c', // ÓÒÔÕÖŌ
    'ss': '\u00df', // ß (s sharp)
    'SS': '\u1e9e', // ẞ (Capital sharp s)
    'u' : '\u00fa\u00f9\u00fb\u00fc\u016f', // úùûüů
    'U' : '\u00da\u00d9\u00db\u00dc\u016e' // ÚÙÛÜŮ
  };
  */
  // modify the above defaults as follows
  $.extend($.tablesorter.characterEquivalents, {
    "ae": "\u00e6", // expanding characters æ Æ
    "AE": "\u00c6",
    "oe": "\u00f6\u0153", // œ Œ
    "OE": "\u00d6\u0152",
    "d": "\u00f0", // Eth (ð Ð)
    "D": "\u00d0",
    "o": "\u00f3\u00f2\u00f4\u00f5", // remove ö because it's in the oe now
    "O": "\u00d3\u00d2\u00d4\u00d5" // remove Ö because it's in the OE now
  });

  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    // Enable use of the characterEquivalents reference
    sortLocaleCompare: true,
    // if false, upper case sorts BEFORE lower case
    ignoreCase: true


  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add 'debug' directive and you will see, that first column sorting is recognised as digits.

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
// Enable use of the characterEquivalents reference
sortLocaleCompare: true,
// if false, upper case sorts BEFORE lower case
ignoreCase: true,
 debug: true,
 headers: { 
            0: { 
                sorter:'text' 
            } 
        } 
  });
```